# как правильно убить сессию из iframe того же домена?

Tags: php, сессия

Есть основной домен, там открывается сессия. В этом окне висит iframe и при определенных условии он должен убить сессию. Я это делаю session_unset(), session_destroy() но это не помогает .
Кто подскажет как их связать?
Если открыть фрейм в отдельной вкладке то сессия умирает а вот внутри страницы  - нет

в основном окне

```html
session_set_cookie_params(10800);
session_start();
$print_r($_SESSION);


в iframe
session_start();
 /////
session_destroy();
```

Comment: Что значит "не помогает"? Что вы ожидаете и что просиходит вместо ожидаемого? И при чём тут iframe?

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы переменные хрянящиеся там в $_SESSION удаллились - вот что значит не помогает

Comment: И что конкретно вы для этого делаете? Где, когда и как вы пытаетесь вызывать session_unset/session_destroy?

Comment: Скрипт в iframe выполняет session_unset

Comment: А конкретнее? И как вы проверяли, что действительно выполняет?

Comment: И что такое "и при определенных условии"? Наступают ли они вообще? И если наступают, то вызывают ли скрипт? Что у вас в целом происходит-то вообще? Нужны подробности и вообще [mcve]

Comment: наступают все условия, в этом можно не сомневаться. Проверяю я print_r($_SESSION).

Comment: Не сомневаться можно только в коде, покажите [mcve] демонстрирующий проблему

Comment: нажимаю f5 переменные в основном окне не умирают

Comment: Вы написали выдуманный код, который даже не запускается. Если вы отказываетесь рассказать, что у вас происходит, то мы никак не сможем вам помочь